# WebSphere MQ Q Program

Tags: ibm-mq

Simple question on [Q Program SupportPac](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24000647&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en). Do we install this on the MQ Server or MQ Client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your pick.  Q can connect using bindings or client mode so put it wherever you need it.  If you have a client app that you are trying to debug, Q can use the same channel and CONNAME.  (If the channel uses SSL and your app is Java, you might need to convert the keystore to a kdb format first.)  And of course, Q on the same server as the queue manager can access MQ in bindings mode, provided you have sufficient authority to do so.